# How come $P(Z< -1.5)$ is equal to $P(Z > 1.5)$ which are both equal to $1-P(Z < 1.5)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I can't wrap my head around the idea they are both equal. I mean shouldn't we have 
$P(-Z > 1.5)$ which is not equal to $P(Z < 1.5)$?

Comment: 16 minutes. $ $

Comment: @Did: Um, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution is symmetric about zero, that is why $P(Z < -1.5) = P(Z > 1.5)$ (the two regions of interest are the tails of the distribution). As the normal distribution is a probability distribution, $P(Z \leq 1.5) + P(Z > 1.5) = 1$ (the two regions cover all of the possibile values for $Z$), so $P(Z > 1.5) = 1 - P(Z \leq 1.5)$. As there is zero probability that $Z$ will be precisely $1.5$, $P(Z \leq 1.5) = P(Z < 1.5)$ so $P(Z > 1.5) = 1 - P(Z < 1.5)$.

Comment: wow, ok makes sense now

Comment: In fact, the results are correct for _any_ continuous random variable whose density function is symmetric about $0$, and the assumption of normality is _not_ required in this instance.

Comment: Of course. I didn't use the normality assumption anywhere.